# How do I enable the character count when typing an sms?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sms, sony-xperia-u

I have a Sony Xperia U with Android 2.3.7 Gingerbread. I don't know exactly if the SMS composer is Android's or belongs to Sony's launcher, so I don't know if the question applies to all Gingerbread users or only Sony's.

I'd like to see the character count when typing SMSs, and I can't see that setting available. Do you know if it's possible to enable it or I need to replace the texting application? Also, is it possible to do it without rooting or flashing?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the SMS apps in the Play Store? I'll wager some of them have the feature you're looking for.

Comment: @AlEverett I considered that option, but I think it's a basic feature that should be somewhere in the default application. And I would avoid to install another one for a such simple thing.